# Router port forwarding using cling

Tags: java, port, router, forwarding

I'm currently developing an Match Maker for a game called GTA, the problem is that the game server uses 7777 port and I need to open this port to the world to allow players to join in the server, and I don't want the users to make any changes on their routers.

Note: The game server is not mine, I can not modify its source code, I just launch it.

So, I discovered that [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/) can handle with port forwarding, but I can't make it to work!

Code I'm using:

```
public static void openports() throws UnknownHostException {
    InetAddress i = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());

    UpnpService upnpServiceTCP = new UpnpServiceImpl(new PortMappingListener(new PortMapping(7777, i.getHostAddress(), PortMapping.Protocol.TCP)));
    upnpServiceTCP.getControlPoint().search(new STAllHeader());

    UpnpService upnpServiceUDP = new UpnpServiceImpl(new PortMappingListener(new PortMapping(7777, i.getHostAddress(), PortMapping.Protocol.UDP)));
    upnpServiceUDP.getControlPoint().search(new STAllHeader());
}
```

anyone has any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using below code

```
private void doPortForwarding() {

        PortMapping[] desiredMapping = new PortMapping[2];
         desiredMapping[0] = new PortMapping(8123, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
                PortMapping.Protocol.TCP, " TCP POT Forwarding");

         desiredMapping[1] = new PortMapping(8123, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
                    PortMapping.Protocol.UDP, " UDP POT Forwarding");


         UpnpService upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl();
         RegistryListener registryListener = new PortMappingListener(desiredMapping);
         upnpService.getRegistry().addListener(registryListener);

        upnpService.getControlPoint().search();

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Cling have a few problems when you want portforwad ports like this.
You should use this code:

```
UpnpServiceImpl upnpService = null;
PortMapping[] arr = new PortMapping[2];

    arr[0] = new PortMapping(7777, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), PortMapping.Protocol.TCP,"My Port Mapping1");       
    arr[1] = new PortMapping(7777, InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), PortMapping.Protocol.UDP,"My Port Mapping2");

    upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl(new PortMappingListener(arr));            

    upnpService.getControlPoint().search();
```

Do not forget to turn on UPnP on the router.

And when your communication ends you should turn it off like this:

```
upnpService.shutdown();
```